# Sealed beer can doesn't feel full

Tags: craft-beers, cans

I have a can of local craft brew from a smallish brewery that has some "give" when I squeeze it.  According to the can it was canned about 1 month ago.  Other cans in the six pack feel normal and taste great.  I can't see any evidence of leaking.

Is this normal and safe to drink or should I just toss it?  If I open it and it has no carbonation then there's obviously no point in even trying to drink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is local brew may I suggest sending a message to the brewer and asked about it. for any more advice, I do think it is still good but if you want to be safe just message them for why this 1 can feels so light.

edit

after the comment of  Eric Shain

"Even if it is safe, if it is underfilled it should be replaced. – Eric Shain"

Comment: Even if it is safe, if it is under filled it should be replaced.